# I'm getting issues in running nightwatch test cases in local configuration. For all browsers there's different issue which are listed as below:

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

Edge:
Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "Unable to create new service: EdgeDriverService"

Chrome:
Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService"

Firefox:

```
Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binale to find binary in default locatiory flag set on the command line"
```

Comment: Can you share your nightwatch config file ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a configuration issue. Assuming that you are using nightwatchjs without selenium, you need to ensure that the runner is able to find the chromedriver and geckodriver binaries. You can check my sample repo [here](https://github.com/spnraju/demo-nightwatchjs-tests/blob/main/nightwatch.conf.js). If you are using selenium, then you can check [here](https://github.com/spnraju/nightwatchjs-selenium-example/blob/main/nightwatch.conf.js).